# API Requests from Angular Web App to Express API not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, express

**Context**: I'm working on a CRM system, on the first load I make an `HTTP GET` request to an express API. This works the first time as expected. 
Call history: `ngOnInit() > fetch(...)`
This works as intended.

**Problem**:
When I make a second request later, it does not working. The Function gets called as expected, but then nothing happens.

**This Function gets called from the UI**

```js
deleteFahrzeug = async (fahrzeugID: number) => {
  await this.api.deleteFahrzeug(fahrzeugID);
  let fahrzeug = this.fahrzeugeListe.find(f => f.id === fahrzeugID);
  if (fahrzeug === undefined) {
    throw "Fahrzeug nicht gefunen";
  } else {
    let i = this.fahrzeugeListe.indexOf(fahrzeug);
    this.fahrzeugeListe.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

**And this Methods makes the API Call (its a Angular Service called api.serivce.ts)**

```js
public deleteFahrzeug = async (id: number): Promise<any> => await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    // tslint:disable
    console.log(`${this.apiURL}/Fahrzeuge?x=delete&fb=id&fi=${id}`);
    const f1 = await this.httpClient.get(`${this.apiURL}/Fahrzeuge?x=delete&fb=id&fi=${id}`);
    resolve(f1);
  } catch (e) {
    reject(e);
  }
});
```

**And this Method is the working one (also in part of the Angular Service)**

```js
public getAlleFahrzeuge = async (feld?: string): Promise<Observable<Fahrzeug[]>> => await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    if (feld === undefined) {
      const f1 = await this.httpClient.get<Fahrzeug[]>(`${this.apiURL}/Fahrzeuge?x=get&fe=*`);
      resolve(f1);
    } else {
      const f2 = await this.httpClient.get<Fahrzeug[]>(`${this.apiURL}/Fahrzeuge?x=get&fe=${feld}`);
      resolve(f2);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    reject(e);
  }
});
```

I have verified that the Express API is working correctly.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear what should be happening.

I suppose rest servive works and returns the result and some array on the FrontEnd should change when rest called. So, maybe, you have `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your component so it doesn't change.

If I misunderstood something - explain in more detail what is happening in steps

Comment: The Frontend and Backen works. I tested it with a Array of Demo Data, and it all worked as expect. The Problem is that the API Call never gets made. `this.http.get<...>()` does not call the API. I would guess the Problem is with the Angular Service: API. It seems like i can only call one method from the API Service once, and then its no other Method is working anymore.